# Response 302; Need a result like calling curl

Tags: php

I need the same result as when calling `curl` from terminal/consol, even if the answer is **302**. Unfortunately I didn't get any data during my attempts.

```
$ curl bretten.work
<a href="https://www.bretten.work">Moved Permanently</a>.
```

Comment: We can't see over your shoulder, so unless you show us your attempts, we can't tell you why they're not doing what you were hoping.

Comment: @IMSoP I've tried different variations of curl_init(). Likewise from file_get_contents(). I haven't found any encoding that does the same thing as curl. There's no point in posting my trash. I need the answer:```<a href="https://www.bretten.work">Moved Permanently</a>.```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server seems to block requests if no user agent is set. Try this:

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init('http://bretten.work/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'curl/7.68.0');
curl_exec($ch);
```

To diagnose further problems try to compare `curl -vvv https://example.com/` with this:

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init('http://example.com/');

#curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);

$cv = curl_version();
$useragent = 'curl';
if (isset($cv['version'])) {
    $useragent .= '/' . $cv['version'];
}
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
$streamVerboseHandle = fopen('php://temp', 'w+');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $streamVerboseHandle);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if ($result === false) {
    printf("cUrl error (#%d): %s<br>\n",
           curl_errno($ch),
           htmlspecialchars(curl_error($ch)))
           ;
}
rewind($streamVerboseHandle);
$verboseLog = stream_get_contents($streamVerboseHandle);

echo "cUrl verbose information:\n", 
     "<pre>", htmlspecialchars($verboseLog), "</pre>\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

To make php curl follow redirects, the FOLLOWLOCATION setting is needed, as such:

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init('http://bretten.work/');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_exec($curl);
```

See https://evertpot.com/curl-redirect-requestbody/ for more options.

Comment: Thanks @took However, the example provides a different answer as curl.
```<html>
<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
</body>
</html>```